# Magento error: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table

Tags: magento

I am getting this error in the shopping cart after pressing proceed to checkout, any ideas?

here has been an error processing your request 
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table \\’XXXX_mgnt1.magenotification_log\\’ doesn\\’t exist

Trace:

```
#0 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#1 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array) 
#2 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#3 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query(\\\’SELECT `main_ta...\\\’, Array) 
#4 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(419): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query(\\\’SELECT `main_ta...\\\’, Array) 
#5 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(734): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(\\\’SELECT `main_ta...\\\’, Array) 
#6 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(734): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll(\\\’SELECT `main_ta...\\\’, Array) 
#7 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(521): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->_fetchAll(\\\’SELECT `main_ta...\\\’, Array) 
#8 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(566): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->getData() 
#9 /home/celialiu/public_html/lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(268): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->load() 
#10 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php(1) : eval()\\\’d code(383): Varien_Data_Collection->getFirstItem() 
#11 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php(1) : eval()\\\’d code(324): Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data->_getLogger() 
#12 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Magenotification/Helper/Data.php(1) : eval()\\\’d code(76): Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data->getDBLicenseKey() 
#13 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/local/Magestore/Giftvoucher/Model/Payment/Giftvoucher.php(12): Magestore_Magenotification_Helper_Data->checkLicenseKey(\\\’Giftvoucher\\\’) 
#14 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Helper/Data.php(73): Magestore_Giftvoucher_Model_Payment_Giftvoucher->isAvailable(Object(Rewardpoints_Model_Quote)) 
#15 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php(118): Mage_Payment_Helper_Data->getStoreMethods(\\\’1\\\’, Object(Rewardpoints_Model_Quote)) 
#16 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Block/Form/Container.php(44): Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container->getMethods() 
#17 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(238): Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Container->_prepareLayout() 
#18 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(456): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->setLayout(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout)) 
#19 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(472): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->createBlock(\\\’checkout/onepag...\\\’, \\\’checkout.paymen...\\\’) 
#20 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(239): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->addBlock(\\\’checkout/onepag...\\\’, \\\’checkout.paymen...\\\’) 
#21 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->_generateBlock(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element), Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#22 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#23 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(206): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#24 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(210): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks(Object(Mage_Core_Model_Layout_Element)) 
#25 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(344): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->generateBlocks() 
#26 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(269): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->generateLayoutBlocks() 
#27 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(185): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->loadLayout() 
#28 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->indexAction() 
#29 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch(\\\’index\\\’) 
#30 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#31 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#32 /home/celialiu/public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array) 
#33 /home/celialiu/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run(\\\’\\\’, \\\’store\\\’) 
#34 {main}
```

Comment: First thing to do to bring your store back is disable `Magestore Magenotification` extension.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the help. I went to Configuration > Advanced > Advanced and switched off the extension above but the error is still the same...

Comment: Rik, with that option you don't disable the module. You only disable it's output of the blocks. To really disable the module you need to go to `app/etc/modules` in your codebase an find the file `Magestore_Magenotifcation.xml`. Within that file you need to change the `<active>` node to `false`. When cache is enabled you need to flush it after you made this change.

Comment: Thanks Tim, appreciate the help. I followed your instruction and now the error has changed to Fatal error: Class 'Mage_Magenotification_Helper_Data' not found in /home/XXX/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 546

Comment: Hi Tim, I got it to work by following your instruction to switch off a related extension. Your a star!!

Answer (score 0):

With `Configuration > Advanced > Advanced` you only disable the output of the blocks. To really disable the module you need to go to app/etc/modules in your codebase an find the file Magestore_Magenotifcation.xml. Within that file you need to change the  node to false. When cache is enabled you need to flush it after you made this change.